# HTML5 validation error (numeric character reference)

Tags: html, validation

What does following error message mean? How can I make it correct?

```
Line 910, Column 34: A numeric character reference expanded to the C1 controls range.
            <p>One fine body&#133;</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `&#8230;` instead of `&#133;`

**What the spec/message says/means:**

In a nutshell, the spec says HTML documents cannot contain “control characters”, which cover the HTML character entity numbers `&#128;` to `&#159;`

So the advise is to use this `&#8230;`

Comment: For the curious out there, both `&#133;` and `&#8230;` look-alike `...`